# Not able to pass array to second view controller using segue

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass an array from ViewController1 to ViewController2 but not able to , while at the same time if I try to pass anything else it works

I have a struct as follows

```swift
 struct News {
//    var image : String
    var title : String
    var publisherIcon : String
    var publisher : String
    var author : String
    var time : Int

    init(dictionary : [String:Any])
    {
        self.title = dictionary["title"] as? String ?? ""
        self.publisherIcon = dictionary["shortenedLogo"] as? String ?? ""
        self.publisher =  dictionary["publisher"] as? String ?? ""
        self.author = dictionary["author"] as? String ?? ""
        self.time = dictionary["timeToRead"] as? Int ?? 0
    }
}
```

In my ViewController 1 I have

```swift
var model = [News]()
```

My segue code

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! HomeFeedDarkVC
        vc.news = self.model
        vc.testfrom = "Test"

    }
```

In my ViewController 2 I have

```swift
class HomeFeedDarkVC: UIViewController {

    var news = [News]()
    var testfrom = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         print(self.news[0].title)
          print(testfrom)

    }

}
```

The testfrom is passed successfully and "Test" is printed which indicates that the segue is performing correctly

but the array shows index out of range error , which I'm assuming means its empty and didn't pass

also just to test I also did this in View Controller 1 and it prints successfully

```swift
print(self.model[0].title)
```

which means model is not empty but is just not being passes.
What am I doing wrong? and how can I do this?

EDIT:

I should have been more clear the model array is not empty , I parse json data from an api into the array and then I call the segue function

```swift
self.getNews(){response in
                        for dic in response{
                            self.model.append(News(dictionary: dic))
                        }
                        print(self.model[0].title)
                        print(self.model[10].publisherIcon)
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "newsDataFromLogin", sender: self)
                        let homeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeFeedDarkVC") as! HomeFeedDarkVC

                        self.present(homeVC, animated: true)
                    }
```

here both the print statements for model[0] and model[10] are printing the respective data correctly. The model array is not empty

EDIT 2 : I added this in the prepareSegue function to show how the model array is not empty

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! HomeFeedDarkVC
        vc.news = self.model
        vc.testfrom = "Test"
        vc.titlefrom = self.model[2].title  //Added line

    }
```

I printed titlefrom in View Controller 2

This is my log

```
How People Redirect Their Careers After Getting Laid Off //model[0].title
https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/images.tapin/logo/publishers/harvard_business_review/harvard_shortened.png // model[10].publisherIcon
8 Ways to Read the Books You Wish You Had Time For //titlefrom
```

Comment: Are you sure that `self.model` is not empty before you assign it?  Where did you print that title?  In `prepare(for:)`?

Comment: I have initialised it as empty because if I just declare it , it will return an error. But before the segue is performed the model array is populated with 20 News objects. I am sure of that as I also did a print(model.count) and it printed 20

Comment: I would suggest you declare `news` as `[News]?` and unwrap it when required or as `[News]!` - this will confirm whether you are attempting to access the property before it has been assigned to.

Comment: It shows an error when I try to declare it like that  "Expected member name or constructor call after type name"

Comment: `var news:[News]?`

Comment: Okay I declared it as "var news : [News]?" and used it as this "print(news![0].title)" and yes it confirms that it is empty as I got a "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Which means model wasn't passed to news. Why is this?

Comment: Because you are accessing the model before you have assigned to the property. Set some breakpoints and use the debugger to see what is happening.

Comment: I can see from your edited question that you aren't using a segue to present the new VC, so `prepare(for:)` won't be called

Comment: Check my edit 2 as well , prepare(for: ) is being called , since both "testfrom" and "titlefrom" are being passed correctly.

Comment: You are calling both `performSegue` and presenting a VC - you just need one

Comment: yes that did it. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var model = [News]()` creates an empty array. You pass that to a new controller and then try to access the first element of this empty array. That's your issue.
Seems like there are no issues in passing it between controllers, you just try to access a nonexistent element. Plain old "index out of bounds" error, just like the error message told you. Add some objects and you will see that it works. If you want to check if it was passed at all (but that's a guarantee, no reason why it shouldn't), just do `print(self.model)`, `print(self.model.count)` or `print(self.model.first?.title)` (this will print `nil` since the first element doesn't exist, again.)

Comment: The model array is not empty when I try to pass it , I have edited the question for more info

Comment: What's up with the let homeVC = ... and self.present() ? "performSegue" should suffice actually. Would you like to share some code? Maybe what you see is the homeVC who you didn't pass the value to? Try to remove those 2 lines or to add homeVC.news = self.model.

Comment: That is for switching to the second view controller. So as soon as the segue is performed I navigate to the "HomeDarkVC" ViewController. Which is my segue destination as well. performSegue wouldn't suffice in navigating to that view controller right?

Comment: Could you maybe just link a zip of your project?

Comment: It's solved , it was because I was presenting the view controller as well as performing a segue while I needed only 1 as you and 1 other user above said

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're passing an empty array. For an empty array, attempting to fetch the item at index 0 will give an index out of range error, exactly as you are reporting.

Where do you add items to `model` in view controller 1?